# MYSQL How to generate sequence and use distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

So here I'm trying to generate a sequence Number and use the command DISTINCT in MYSQL so here is my first query, this query work

```
SELECT DISTINCT(concat( ui.firstname, ' ', ui.mname, ' ', ui.lastname )) AS Fullname
     , ui.status as 'Type of Learners'
     , ui.barangay as 'Barangay'
     , ui.nature_of_work as 'Status'
     , ui.level 'Year Level'
     , date(ui.member_since) as 'Date Registered'
     , d.survey_at_what_blh as 'Survey at What BLH'
  FROM daily_report d
  JOIN userinfo ui 
    ON d.userid = ui.id
```

but when i try to add the generate sequence number query in my code i recieve a lot of unexpected token

```
SET @row := 0;
SELECT  @row := @row + 1 as Number
     , DISTINCT(concat( ui.firstname, ' ', ui.mname, ' ', ui.lastname )) AS Fullname
     , ui.status as 'Type of Learners'
     , ui.barangay as 'Barangay'
     , ui.nature_of_work as 'Status'
     , ui.level 'Year Level'
     , date(ui.member_since) as 'Date Registered'
     , d.survey_at_what_blh as 'Survey at What BLH'
  FROM daily_report d
  JOIN userinfo ui 
    ON d.userid = ui.id t
     , (SELECT @row := 0)  r
```

Where do you think my mistake here? I been fixing this for days now

Comment: I think your mistake is not reading this...  [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use row_number() to get a sequence. You just need to mention by which column you need it to be ordered. I used d.userid.

```
SELECT Row_Number()over(order by d.userid) sequence,
DISTINCT concat( ui.firstname, ' ', ui.mname, ' ', ui.lastname ) AS Fullname
     , ui.status as 'Type of Learners'
     , ui.barangay as 'Barangay'
     , ui.nature_of_work as 'Status'
     , ui.level 'Year Level'
     , date(ui.member_since) as 'Date Registered'
     , d.survey_at_what_blh as 'Survey at What BLH'
  FROM daily_report d
  JOIN userinfo ui 
    ON d.userid = ui.id
```

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: Actually i just added row_number() in a query which is working according to the person who asked the question. And offcourse DISTINCT is not a function.

Comment: But DISTINCT(concate( a,b)) works just fine.

Comment: Well, yes, if you think misleading is fine. `DISTINCT(CONCAT(a,b))` is the same as `DISTINCT CONCAT(a,b)`. The outer parentheses serve no purpose.

Comment: Misleading is never fine. I should have corrected it. Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I have edited my answer.

Comment: And note that we'd normally opt for CONCAT_WS() in this instance

Comment: its okay now i did this SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(@row := @row + 1,' ',ui.firstname, ' ', ui.mname, ' ', ui.lastname, ' in ' ) as 'Regular Users'